# "WARNING: Unable to find required classes" when making a web service client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have to make a web service client from an wsdl file. I have followed tutorial to create and test the service client in the eclipse wizard, and (I thought that I have implemented the code to call the service), but I keep getting this stack trace, I know its maybe trivial but I didn't manage to find anything on internet. I have attached these libraries to the path, so i cant understand what this is, I appreciate any help, first time dealing with web services. I am not sure if it is ok to post entire stack trace here, its quite big, but here is part of it.....

```
Dec 8, 2010 7:10:31 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and          javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Fault occurred while processing.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Fault occurred while processing.
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
atorg.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at ch.contract.BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.getCourses(BookCourseServiceEndpointServiceSoapBindingStub.java:287)
at ch.contract.RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.getCourses(RemoteBookCourseServiceProxy.java:62)
at ch.controllers.BookCourseController.getAllCourses(BookCourseController.java:23)
at ch.gui.CourseListFrame.initComponents(CourseListFrame.java:60)
at chbookcourse.gui.CourseListFrame.start(CourseListFrame.java:37)
at ch.bookcourse.Runner.main(Runner.java:9)

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:usis-MacBook-Pro-15.local
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure `activation.jar` from the [JAF (Java Activation Framework)](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/javabeans/jaf11.html) is in your classpath.

Comment: @Asaph: It is there!!! I wrote up in description, i have activation.jar and the mail.jar!

Comment: @Julia: According to the stacktrace, the class `javax.activation.DataHandler` cannot be found. That class is normally found in `activation.jar`. I re-read your question and see no mention of `activation.jar`. Are you certain your running program is using the same classpath you're checking?

Comment: @Julia, you may have it, but it is not present in your classpath at the time of the exception.

Comment: @Asaph: You were right! I added activation, but it was still jar.zip... :/ Sorry for that. I have new stacktrace, quick opinion on that? Or i should edit orignial post??  AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Fault occurred while processing.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:Fault occurred while processing.
 at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
 at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)

Comment: @Julia: The stacktrace is too difficult to read as a comment. Please post your new stacktrace in a new question. Also, if you found my answer to this question helpful, please mark it correct.

Comment: @Asaph: I have make new question, can u have look pls:)

Comment: @Asaph - Does not work anymore even after adding activation.jar to the build path. Is it okay if I ignore the warning ?

Comment: directly fetch it from http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/

Answer (score 4):

I solved this warning/error on tomcat 8 with eclipse birt reporting viewer.

Fetch the latest ones from:

- http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/

and place them into the installation directory (just like in classpath):

- /apache-tomcat-v/lib/

this should solve your problem